# How to make several drives one large hard drive?

Tags: drive

Just wondering how I would go about make say three 1tb drives one large volume?  This way I don't need to section things off to different hard drives, and Ubuntu/Linux can just assign the data where it sees fit.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The magic letters are [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29)

> LVM is suitable for:
>
> - Managing large hard disk farms by **letting you add disks, replace disks, copy and share contents** from one disk to another without
>     disrupting service (hot swapping).
> - On small systems (like a desktop at home), instead of having to estimate at installation time how big a partition might need to be in
>     the future, LVM allows you to **resize your disk partitions easily as
>     needed**.
> - Making backups by taking "snapshots".
> - **Creating single logical volumes of multiple physical volumes or entire hard disks** (somewhat similar to RAID 0, but more similar to
>     JBOD), allowing for dynamic volume resizing.
>
> One can think of LVM as a thin software layer on top of the hard disks
>   and partitions, which creates an illusion of continuity and
>   ease-of-use for managing hard-drive replacement, repartitioning, and
>   backup.

Here's a [HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/)